# why do I need a cast in this situation?

Tags: java, generics

if i have a method defined.

```
public static <T> T getSomeTea(Class<T> returnType) {
   //do stuff and return a T
}

public static <T> T getSomeSpecialTea(T someVal) {
   T someTea = (T) getSomeTea(someVal.getClass());
}
```

in getSomeSpecialTea, why do I need to cast the return from getSomeTea.  it would seem to me the cast is unneccesary, but perhaps i'm missing something important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object.getClass()` isn't generic, so your code is effectively:

```
public static <T> T getSomeSpecialTea(T someVal) {
   Class<?> clazz = someVal.getClass();
   T someTea = (T) getSomeTea(clazz);
}
```

At that point is it clearer why you need the cast? (Not that the cast will really anything at execution time, of course...) You're not calling `<T>getSomeTea()` which is what you really *want* to be doing, effectively.

It's just another case of Java generics being a bit of a pain :(

Answer (score 1):

An unfortunate erasure on the return type of `getClass()` that bugs many people.

You can have a utility method that returns the unerased type

```
public static <T> Class<? extends T> myGetClass(T instance)
    return (Class<? extends T>)instance.getClass();

public static <T> T getSomeSpecialTea(T someVal) 
   T someTea = getSomeTea( myGetClass(someVal) );
```